# Reference for complex interpolation for the product of two normed space

Tags: reference-request, interpolation-theory

Let $X=X_1\times X_2$ and $Y=Y_1\times Y_2$ and 
$(X_i,Y_i)$ are interpolation couple. Then it seems obvious that 
$$
[X,Y]_{\theta}=[X_1,Y_1]_\theta \times [X_2,Y_2]_\theta 
$$
for every 
$\theta\in (0,1)$. Is there any reference for this result. I have checked many books. But, it seems that nobody state it.

Comment: have you found a proof (or reference) for this?